# NodeJS: Passing a variable into a nested function

Tags: node.js, controller, cron, dependencies

I am trying to pass a service which was injected in a dependency. The first call of that function works. But when I call the injected function within another nested function I get an error.

Code of the Controller:

class CronScheduleController {

```
constructor(log, calculationService) {
    this.log = log;
    this.calculationService = calculationService;
}

async weeklyCronJob() {

    this.log.info('Weekly CRON Job is running');

    var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();     

    var job = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function () {
        this.log.info('Weekly CRON Job Started');
    });

  }
}
```

I get the first log message => 'Weekly CRON Job is running'

But the second log message throws the error => 'Weekly CRON Job Started'

The error is :

> /controllers/cronSchdule.js:28
>               logger.info('Weekly CRON Job Started');
>                      ^
>
> TypeError: logger.info is not a function

Can anyone help to resolve this./

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean log.info is not a function?? ,Can you share your full code snippet?

Comment: log is a different  function. in all modules it works. But this is the first time I am calling it inside a function. The first call of the function executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are inside a function `this` keyword does not represent the class but the lexical scope of the function try an arrow function (assumed ES6 since you are using `async` `await`)

```
constructor(log, calculationService) {
    this.log = log;
    this.calculationService = calculationService;
}

async weeklyCronJob() {

    this.log.info('Weekly CRON Job is running');

    var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();

    var job = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, () => {
        this.log.info('Weekly CRON Job Started');
    });

}
```

If not create a refrence object then access the class using the refrence,

```
constructor(log, calculationService) {
    this.log = log;
    this.calculationService = calculationService;
}

async weeklyCronJob() {

    this.log.info('Weekly CRON Job is running');

    var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
    var that = this; // <== HERE

    var job = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function() {
        that.log.info('Weekly CRON Job Started'); // <== HERE
    });

}
```

Comment: Both solutions worked. I used the es6 version. Thanks brother